# definition of the trace by conjugates and using the characteristic polynomial

Tags: finite-fields, field-trace

The trace of an element $\alpha \in \Bbb F_{q^m}$ over $\Bbb F_q$ is defined to be the sum of all its conjugates, i.e. $$\mathrm{Tr}_{F/K}(\alpha)=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\alpha^{q^i}.$$

I have also seen it defined as follows: if $f(x)\in \Bbb F[x]$ of degree $d$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then 
$$g(x)=(f(x))^{\frac{m}{d}}=x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0$$
$$=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^q)\cdots(x-\alpha^{q^{m-1}})$$ is its characteristic polynomial and therefore by comparison of the coefficients $\mathrm{Tr}_{F/K}(\alpha)=-a_{m-1}$.

Can anyone clarify why the last equality holds?

Comment: If you multiply $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^q)\cdots$, the coefficient on $x^{m-1}$ will be $-\alpha-\alpha^q-\cdots$

Comment: Ok I see it from your comment, but if for example, $f(x)=x^d+b_{d-1}x^{d-1}+\cdots+b_0$, then how can I find the trace directly from here?

Comment: If you raise that $f(x)$ to power $m/d$ the coefficient of $x^{m-1}$ will be $(m/d)\cdot b_{d-1}$.